# Facebook Paper - How to swipe up to zoom the UIScrollView at the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiscrollview

I am trying to develop something similar. If you are familiar of Facebook Paper, how does it actually achieve this behavior? Specifically, in its main view, there is a `UIScrollView` located at the bottom which contains lots of `UIView` of user posts, when you swipe it up, the `UIScrollView` can take to full screen mode.

I have tried with the following code but it doesn't seem to work well:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    _scaleValue += 1.0f;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, _scaleValue);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"whatever" context:nil];
    _scrollView.transform = transform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Facebook Pager / Paper ?

Comment: Sorry....corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it [here](http://gist.github.com/chroman/8847406), it does exactly what I wanted to do.